# I keep getting a duplicate case error

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Selection
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        char key = 'A';
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a letter to find the corresponding digit on a cellphone: ");
        int digit;
        switch (key) {

            case 'A' & 'B' & 'C': digit = 2;
                break;

            case 'D' & 'E' & 'F': digit = 3;
                break;

            case 'G' & 'H' & 'I': digit = 4;
                break;

            case 'J' & 'K' & 'L': digit = 5;
                break;

            case 'M' & 'N' & '0': digit = 6;
                break;

            case 'P' & 'Q' & 'R' & 'S': digit = 7;
                break;

            case 'T' & 'U' & 'V': digit = 8;
                break;

            case 'W' & 'X' & 'Y' & 'Z': digit = 9;
                break;

            default: System.out.println("There is no matching digit for that character.");

            System.out.println("The letter " + key + " corresponds to the number " + digit + " on a      cellphone.");
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I have so far. Basically, I need to make something that takes alphabetical character input and displays what digit corresponds to that letter on a cellphone, and accepts only capital letters and displays an error when something else is entered. The last thing I want is someone to do it for me, I just want guidance.

Comment: What do you think `&` does?

Answer (score 3):

The `&` operator isn't doing what you think here.  It's performing a bitwise-and on the bits in your characters, and some of the cases have a result that is the same.  According to my IDE,

```
'A' & 'B' & 'C' => '@'
'G' & 'H' & 'I' => '@'
'P' & 'Q' & 'R' & 'S' => 'P'
'W' & 'X' & 'Y' & 'Z' => 'P'
```

Even if there weren't duplicate cases, your code wouldn't work, because you'd have cases for characters you didn't expect.  To have the same code executed for multiple cases, try this:

```
case A:
case B:
case C:
    digit = 2;
    break;
case D:
case E:
case F:
    digit = 3;
    break;
// and so on
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to play around with it some more.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you meant

```
case 'A':
case 'B':
case 'C': domSomethingHere(); break

case 'E':
case 'F':
case 'G': domSomethingHere(); break
```

Comment: Ah, okay. So would this method even be the best for what I'm looking to do?